# Unexpected token on server-side rendered React with CSS

Tags: typescript

I am writing a server-side renderer Node.JS app in Typescript. And I use `react-dom/server` library to generate the raw HTML string of my React application. I am now having trouble rendering my React component that is importing a `css` file. Here is the error I'm seeing when I'm starting my Node.js app:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { .className {
```

As you can see, it is failing at reading `css` syntax in `js`. Is there a specific configuration in Typescript to transpile `css` files to be valid `js` files?

There are alternatives to this but, these alternatives are wildly going off to my expected solution, which is to transpile `css` syntax to be readable in NodeJS.

These are the alternatives I tried:
1) [ignore-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles) package. This works, but just like what the npm package is used for, it ignores the style, hence removing the css from my initial server-side rendered HTML string.

2) [styled-components](https://styled-components.com). While I like the concept of CSS in JS. I feel like this is an overkill for smaller projects.

My tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "esnext.asynciterable",
      "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib",

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "resolveJsonModule": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```